# Why doesn't TypeScript eagerly simplify silly union types?

Tags: typescript

These types really are the same, but are represented differently in error messages and language service help tooltips. Why?

```
type Obj = { a: number }

// hovering over this shows:
// type SillyObj = { a: number; } | { a: number; b: number; }
type SillyObj = { a: number } | { a: number, b: number }

declare const obj: Obj;
declare const sillyObj: SillyObj;

// but the two types are inter-assignable!
// shouldn't SillyObj's representation be simplified
// to `{ a: number }`?
let check1: Obj = sillyObj; // OK
let check2: SillyObj = obj; // OK

// this error message is just wrong
// Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SillyObj'.
//   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: number; b: number; }': a, b
let check3: SillyObj = {} // OK
```

Comment: I saw a comment on github, something about keeping source fidelity.

Comment: Excess property checking also goes wrong if you collapse unions as suggested

Comment: I’m getting flashbacks to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386

Comment: @jcalz can you give an example of excess property checking going wrong if redundant unions are simplified away? I thought only types inferred from object literals are 'exact' and that other types are 'open', meaning that there is no such thing as an excess property in these cases: { a: number, foo: 'foo' } is a fine `Obj` (from the example in the OP). Also, great link!

Comment: It looks like @jcal

Comment: I hope @MaxHeiber was not abducted in the middle of commenting.  If you're there, please let us know that you're safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are talking about is called "subtype collapsing" as mentioned in the [GitHub issue introducing union types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/805).  It's part of the general concept of [absoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#Some_additional_laws_for_unions_and_intersections) and I've asked for [more support for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16386) in the past.

As you noticed, this collapsing *does* happen when it comes to checking concrete types for assignability.  That is, the types `A | (A & B)` and `A` are seen by the compiler as mutually assignable when `A` and `B` aren't generic.

But it doesn't happen in quickinfo/IntelliSense, and there is a fairly compelling reason for that: [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  Object types in TypeScript are usually considered "open", in that you can extend a type by adding extra properties.  An if this were always the case, then `SillyObj` would be completely equivalent to `Obj`.

The alternative to open types is "closed" or ["exact"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) types, where objects are not allowed to have extra properties. And TypeScript treats "fresh" object literals as needing to conform to a closed version of a type instead of the normal open version.  Suddenly, then, `SillyObj` is not considered to be completely equivalent to `Obj`:

```
const s: SillyObj = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // okay
const o: Obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // error!  "b" does not exist in Obj
```

If `SillyObj` were aggressively absorbed/collapsed/reduced to `Obj`, then the excess property checking would stop you from assigning a `b` property.

Now there are probably ways to give you both true subtype collapsing and maintaining excess property checking, but they'd need some actual support for exact types in the language, and it isn't there yet.

---

Also, I wouldn't consider the error message "wrong", exactly.  This much is certainly true:

```
// Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'SillyObj'.
```

This part is also technically true, but misses the nuance that the error will go away if you add only an `a` property:

```
//   Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ a: number; b: number; }': a, b
```

This is a hard-to-avoid consequence of automated error messages.  If a value is not assignable to a union, it is because it is not assignable to any constituent of the union.  Either the error message can mention *all* of the constituents, which would be incredibly verbose, or it only mentions *some* of the constituents, which could lead you to believe that the only way to fix the error is to make the value assignable to the mentioned constituents.   I'd probably say the error here is "misleading", not "wrong".

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!